# How do I multiply an input variable?

Tags: jquery, variables

How do I multiply the number that is put into my input using Javascript?

This is a total beginner question - you are a good person for helping.

html

```
<input type="number" id="height" value="0" />
```

javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function display_height() {
        var new_height = $("#height").val() * 3);
        $("new_height").show();
    });
});
```

Comment: `.val()` always returns a string. You'll need to turn it into a number if you're going to do some math with it. `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()` are your friends.

Comment: @ahren - the `*` operator implicitly converts its operands to numbers so there's no need in this case. See the details [in the spec](http://es5.github.com/#x11.5).

Comment: @ahren: that's not entirely true

Comment: wow, didn't know that... although, it's pretty safe to always just do it, as `+` doesn't.

Comment: You have a syntax error and a semantical error in your code. The closing parenthesis after `3` and that certainly there is no element `<new_height>` in your HTML. Last but not least you shouldn't put your function into $(document).ready()

Comment: In addition to the multiplication tips already given, why are you doing "new_height".show(); ? do you have an element with id new_height? you should change that to 
 $("#new_height").show();

Comment: What do you want to do with the new value, put it back into the same input, or...? @ryadavilli - `new_height` was a variable holding the multiplied value, it doesn't make sense for it to be an element id.

Comment: After the input is entered I simply want it to display on the page, similar to this radio button functionality

http://jsfiddle.net/rEK87/

Comment: can't a string be a number? no?

Comment: @nnnnnn Very true, which is why i had asked if there was an element with that id. But it seems it is only a local variable.

Comment: _"can't a string be a number?"_ - A string is not a number, but depending on the particular string it can be _converted_ to a number. Some JS operators do this conversion automatically, including the `*` multiplication operator, but some do _not,_ e.g., the `+` addition/concatenation operator. If your string was typed by the user you need to validate it in some way to be sure it really is a number, or (depending on what you do with it) you'll get errors.

Comment: Ok, it looks like I don't need to convert it in this instance because it is a drop down list, but I should parse it just as good practice

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no `show` method on a string. Try alerting your height instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function display_height() {
        var new_height = $("#height").val() * 3;
        alert(new_height);
    }
    display_height();
});
```

Additionally, you had minor problems like mismatched parentheses and braces, which I have corrected.

What I suspect you actually want is for the user to be able to multiply input, in which case you need a button:

```
<input id="multiply" type="button" value="Multiply!">
```

and a click handler:

```
$('#multiply').click(display_height);
```

You can see a demonstration here: http://jsfiddle.net/4wgaE/1/

To parse a string to a number, use `parseFloat` like this:

```
var new_height = parseFloat( $("#height").val() ) * 3;
```

Comment: so it looks like val can be used but its better to use parseInt() or ParseFloat()?

Comment: @JoeIsaacson Yes, it is generally better to be sure your value has been converted to numeric type, instead of hoping the context you are using it in will result in automatic conversion. `parseFloat`, not `ParseFloat` though.

Comment: Joe - It's not a choice between `val()` and `parseInt()`: you still need `val()` to obtain the content of the input element in the first place, but you then use `parseInt()` (or some other method) to convert that value - which will be a string - to a number.

Comment: @JoeIsaacson `$('#height')` is the input itself (technically a jQuery collection, but close enough). `$('#height').val()` is its value. `parseFloat( $("#height").val() )` is the value, converted to a number.